# FirebaseDatabaseSwift via cocoapods

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, cocoapods

Help!  I can't seem to load FirebaseDatabaseSwift via cocoapods.

pod 'FirebaseDatabaseSwift', '>= 9.0.0'

gives the error:
"None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `FirebaseDatabaseSwift (>= 9.0.0)`."

Any suggestions how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `pod 'FirebaseDatabaseSwift', '> 8.0-beta'`

Version 9.0.0 of FirebaseDatabaseSwift has not published yet.

Comment: Thanks Paul!  Just for future reference- how can I find what the latest published version is?  I read that 9.0.0 was out of beta for GA in the release notes.

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases or https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios